# When during the socket lifetime should I set the TCP_QUICKACK option?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

I know why I should use it, but I'm not sure where to put the setsockopt in my socket code.

It is clear to me that it can be modified by the inner mechanisms of the socket api, but when exactly should I set the TCP_QUICKACK option with setsockopt?

Should I set it at the socket creation then after (or before?) each receive and sends? Or only receives?

Should I check that the option is already set?

Answer (score 8):

> When should I set the TCP_QUICKACK option?

The IETF offers [TCP Tuning for HTTP, draft-stenberg-httpbis-tcp-03](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-stenberg-httpbis-tcp-03). Section 4.4 of the document explains:

> Delayed ACK [RFC1122] is a mechanism enabled in most TCP stacks that
> causes the stack to delay sending acknowledgement packets in response
> to data.  The ACK is delayed up until a certain threshold, or until
> the peer has some data to send, in which case the ACK will be sent
> along with that data.  Depending on the traffic flow and TCP stack
> this delay can be as long as 500ms.
>
> This interacts poorly with peers that have Nagle's Algorithm enabled.
> Because Nagle's Algorithm delays sending until either one MSS of data
> is provided *or* until an ACK is received for all sent data, delaying
> ACKs can force Nagle's Algorithm to buffer packets when it doesn't
> need to (that is, when the other peer has already processed the
> outstanding data).
>
> Delayed ACKs can be useful in situations where it is reasonable to
> assume that a data packet will almost immediately (within 500ms) cause
> data to be sent in the other direction.  In general in both HTTP/1.1
> and HTTP/2 this is unlikely: therefore, disabling Delayed ACKs can
> provide an improvement in latency.
>
> However, the TLS handshake is a clear exception to this case.  For the
> duration of the TLS handshake it is likely to be useful to keep
> Delayed ACKs enabled.
>
> Additionally, for low-latency servers that can guarantee responses to
> requests within 500ms, on long-running connections (such as HTTP/2),
> and when requests are small enough to fit within a small packet,
> leaving delayed ACKs turned on may provide minor performance benefits.
>
> **Effective use of switching off delayed ACKs requires extensive
> profiling**.

Later in the document it offers the following:

> On recent Linux kernels (since Linux 2.4.4), Delayed ACKs can be
> disabled like this:
>
> ```
> int one = 1;
> setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_QUICKACK, &one, sizeof(one));
> ```
>
> Unlike disabling Nagle’s Algorithm, disabling Delayed ACKs on Linux is
> not a one-time operation: processing within the TCP stack can cause
> Delayed ACKs to be re-enabled. As a result, **to use TCP_QUICKACK
> effectively requires setting and unsetting the socket option during
> the life of the connection**.

Comment: It's still not clear when exactly is "during the life of the connection".

Comment: @Nikko - Sorry, I don't have a better answer or explanation. The RFC or ID list the author's email address. Maybe you can reach out to him or her. They may recognize their draft needs an extra section offering guidance. I write to RFC authors on occasion. They are usually quite approachable and happy to help. (Your question piqued my interest because of the socket options).

Comment: I'll have to summon John Naggle too I guess ;). Thanks anyway.